# How to pass values from variant to component

Tags: sxa

I created Rendering Variant contains component field

[image],

I want to pass values from variant like "$item.Name" in Rendering parameters for this component and read the value in component 's cshtml.

[image]

Is this correct way to pass values from variant to component or this not doable??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NVelocity template and pass field's name to a component.

First, create a `VariantTemplate` and add `$item.Name` on `Template` field. You can then use this variant inside a custom component and read its value from `.cshtml` or you can use the component directly and just select `VariantDefinition`.

**See:** https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/create-a-rendering-variant.html

Comment: I recommend not to use NVelocity for the things can be achieved without it.

Answer (score 0):

You can access Rendering Parameters in the backend code (controller/repository or view) easily in SXA. This is a view for Title rendering:

```
@model Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Models.VariantsRenderingModel

<div @Html.Sxa().Component(Model.Rendering.RenderingCssClass ?? "title", Model.Attributes)>
    <div class="component-content">
        @foreach (BaseVariantField variantField in Model.VariantFields)
        {
            @Html.RenderingVariants().RenderVariant(variantField, Model.Item, Model.RenderingWebEditingParams, Model)
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

`VariantsRenderingModel` contains a list of variant fields so you can use them right away (and this is what we are doing there). This model class inherits from `RenderingModelBase` which has plenty of data. One of that is a `Rendering` object which has `Parameters` collection. This is a collection of rendering parameters. You can access them on the view like that:

```
<div>@Model.Rendering.Parameters["MY_CUSTOM_RENDERING_PARAMETER_NAME"]</div>
```

This is how you are accessing the rendering parameres on the view.

Now... with the `$item.Name` which you have there. What did you want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I Know how to access rendering parameters in view but what i need is passing Name of each item in variant to component or reading item in variant inside component.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand... You have all of that data in the backend already. Show me your desired code, maybe this will help me to understand your problem.